# IIS7 - Rewrite for files and subdirectories in Public folder

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7, subdirectory

I'm new to IIS and i've a PHP project with all files in a *public* directory, in such a structure:

- Root/
  - public/

    - index.php
    - login.php
    - sub1/

      - index.php
      - edit.php
    - sub2/

      - index.php
    - src/

      - js/

        - script.js
      - css/

        - theme.css

I need some rewrite rules for:

- hide extension for just PHP files:

  - example.com -> example.com/public/index.php
  - example.com/login -> example.com/public/login.php
  - example.com/sub1/edit -> example.com/public/sub1/edit.php
  - example.com/src/css/theme.css -> example.com/src/css/theme.css
- default index.php for subdirectories, if page is not specified:

  - example.com/sub1/ -> example.com/public/sub1/index.php
  - example.com/sub1/edit -> example.com/public/sub1/edit.php
- optional trailing slash for both pages and subdirectories:

  - example.com/login -> example.com/public/login.php
  - example.com/login/ -> example.com/public/login.php
  - example.com/sub1 -> example.com/public/sub1/index.php
  - example.com/sub1/ -> example.com/public/sub1/index.php
  - example.com/sub1/edit -> example.com/public/sub1/edit.php
  - example.com/sub1/edit/ -> example.com/public/sub1/edit.php

Comment: Then try to write your rules and enable FRT to see how they work (or not work), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: @LexLi Unfortunately i can't change ISS configuration: i just can work on the shared folder and uploads files there, as a normal website. I have to try various code and refresh, until it will works.

Comment: If you cannot modify the remote server, fine. Set up local IIS on your own machine and then test out the rules before uploading remotely. It is pointless to try directly on that remote server, as you are wasting your own time.

Comment: @LexLi ok, i'll try this way. Thank You